# What is considered an abnormal "In Review" time for App Store Connect (iOS) in 2021?

Tags: ios, apple-watch

I recently submitted an app to the iOS app store for review (an Apple watch only app).
From what I have been reading, once the status is "In Review", it typically takes just a few hours (3-4 hours) before the app is approved and ready for sale.  My app has been in review for about 48 hours. Does this warrant emailing Apple and asking about what is causing the delay? Just want to see how "normal" an "In Review" time of several days is? Does anyone have any thoughts/data points about review times in 2021?

Comment: For me it's always been less than an hour, but sometimes they have delays especially on the weekends

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, my previous app took just 4 hours. I wonder if longer review times imply a rejection is coming.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because app store review quirks are off topic.

Comment: Do you know where to go to ask these questions?

Comment: The longest time I had was two days. Usually takes couple of hours.

Comment: In the case of 2 days, was it approved? Or did you realize the delay was due to a problem with the submission?

Comment: Apple dev forums would be fine. Stack Overflow has strict rules.

Comment: ah okay makes sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience today, it took 6h for my submission to change status from "*Waiting for Review*" to "*In Review*". Then it took an extra 2.5h to change status from "*In Review*" to "*Ready For Sale*". Hence a total of 8.5h. The app was submitted for the first time.